# How do I list each value from my_sqli_fetch_row?

Tags: php, sql

I have two sql statements.

1 lists all columns from my table using mysqli_fetch_assoc

The other statements returns a row where id = specific id using mysqli_num_rows

My problem is that with the mysqli_fetch_assoc, I'm able to use something like:

$rowz['Field'] and it returns the value for every single column name. This is perfect, but, I am unable to get every single value in my row as well. In other words, My code lists all fields: id / name / phone... but when I use myqli_fetch_row, it returns the value for just one column over and over. So every field will just show '193' which is the id. I want all fields to show proper value instead of just the same value from one column over and over.

```
   // listing all columns from table

   $sql2 = ("SHOW COLUMNS FROM articles");

   $result55 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);

   echo'<form action="update.php" method="POST">';

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result55) > 0) 
   {

    // to fetch row of specific id

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE  ID='".$id."'";
   $result5 = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

   if (!$result5) {
   echo 'no';
   } 

   $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result5); 

   while($rowz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result55)){

   $z = 0; 

   echo '
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="'.$rowz['Field'].'" 
   value="'.$row[$z].'" />'; 

   }

   }
   echo' </form>';
```

The issue is the name of the input field, where I have '.$row[$z].' it just keeps returning 0 from array which is just the ID column. Hence why I just keep getting 193 over and over. However, the $rowz['Field'] works much better and loops every single time for each existing column. I hope to get: id = 193, name = john, phone = 123-3345 etc.. But instead I get: id = 193, name = 193, phone = 193.

Please send help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$z` is your column index. and it should be your counter, if you want to generate each column values.

```
$z = 0; 
while($rowz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result55)){

    echo '
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="'.$rowz['Field'].'" 
            value="'.$row[$z].'" />'; 
    $z = $z + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. I was trying to do that with $z++ and now with you recommended but for some reason it's not iterating and just keeps returning 0 for value of z :(

Comment: have you removed your `$z=0` outside `while`?

Comment: OMG thank you, I literally just deleted the $z =0 and the it was working except wasn't pulling in ID, then I read your comment and moved the $z = 0 outside of while loop and that did the trick. Seriously thank you so much! This has been like so much searching for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared $z=0 inside the while loop.
Rather you have to declare it before the while loop and increment it inside the loop.
You have used $z as the index for $row which indicates the specific column of the result obtained from the query. 
When you fix it to 0, it means that the first column value only is getting accessed.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result5);
$z=0;

while($rowz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result55))
{

    echo '
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="'.$rowz['Field'].'" 
            value="'.$row[$z].'" />'; 

    $z = $z +1;

}
```